# Throw an exception if room doesn't exist or is already reserved

Tags: java, exception

I am working on an assignment and I am trying to throw an exception for when the user enters a room, and the room does not exist or is already reserved. I am confused on where to actually put the code block and any help would be appreciated.

Room class

```
 public static int getRoomNumberIfExists(int roomNumber) throws RoomExistException{
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < rooms.size(); i++) {
        if (rooms.get(i).getRoomNumber() == roomNumber) {
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

Exception class

```
public class RoomExistException extends Exception {

public RoomExistException(String message){
    super(message);
}
}
```

Comment: You throw the `RoomExistsException` when you have determined that the room is either non-existent or reserved. You could realize this by checking `index` after the loop. Iff. `index == -1`, then throw the exception, else return `index`.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it that way, you will never be able to throw a new Exception since it would reach the outside. A possible workaround would be to check if index is -1, and then throw an Exception. A better way would be using return directly inside the loop and throwing the Exception outside.
To do this you will have to code a boolean non-static isAvailable method which will check if its not reserved.

```
// in class Room
...
boolean available = true;
...
public boolean isAvailable()
{
    return available;
}
```

And finally, here resides the new static method.

```
public static int getRoomNumberIfExists(int roomNumber) throws RoomExistException
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rooms.size(); i++) 
    {
        Room room = rooms.get(i);
        if (room.getRoomNumber() == roomNumber && room.isAvailable()) 
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    throw new RoomExistException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a list of rooms, or at least is what you let us infer when you post:

```
rooms.get(i)
```

so in the Room class you need to define if not already a method for the  room

```
if (rooms.get(i).isRoomNumberReserved()) {
    throw new RoomExistException("this room is already gone!");
```